# Which one of these phrases is correct? "I and my thoughts" or "Me and my thoughts"?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

> I and my thoughts on website www.___.com

OR

> Me and my thoughts on website www.___.com

Which one of these phrases is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sentence fragments, they're both absolutely fine (though, I think you need to put a definite article in front of the word *website*: *on the website www.___.com*). That's the short answer.

The long answer is whether they're correct or not depends on where in a sentence (a sentence consists of a subject and a predicate) they're going to be found. If at the beginning, then only *I and my thoughts* would be correct as *I* is a subject pronoun while *me* is an object one, which means that it cannot be placed before the predicate as it is the place, at least in English, where only the subject of a sentence is found. Subject pronouns (*I*, *you*, *he*, *she*, *it*, *we* and *they*) are used in places where we expect to see the subject of a sentence. Likewise, objects pronoun (*me*, *you*, *him*, *her*, *it*, *us* and *them*) are used in places where we expect to see objects. An object is a noun or noun phrase governed by an active transitive verb or by a preposition. For example:

> **I and my wife** are going to visit Paris this summer.

We use *I* here because, as we know, the subject of a sentence only works with subject pronouns.

> They gave **me and my wife** a free ride to the city center.

In this case, *gave* is used as a transitive verb. That's why we have to use the object pronoun *me*.

However, in casual speech, it's very common to hear people use object pronouns in places where they should be using subject ones. Although grammatically entirely incorrect, using *me* instead of *I* in this manner has become so commonplace that most people are not even aware of the fact that they're actually making a grammatical mistake. So, it's not unheard of to hear something like this in daily conversation:

> **Me and my wife** are going to visit Paris this summer.

My advise to you: never use this kind of grammar in formal writing; as far as conversational English is concerned, it's entirely up to you to decide which grammar to use as long as you understand the consequences.

Comment: There is no predicate in the OP's question.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you for your comment. I took care of that. Take a second look please.

Answer (score 0):

The former can be used as a subject and the latter as an object.

I was invited to dinner. 
They invited me to dinner.